# How to execute a command in all subdirectories using Bash

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, unix

I have a directory structure composed by:

```
iTunes/Music/${author}/${album}/${song.mp3}
```

I implemented a script to strip my mp3 bitrate to 128 kbps using lame (which works on a single file at time).

My 'normalize_mp3.sh' looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
SAVEIFS=$IFS
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
for f in *.mp3
do
  lame --cbr $f __out.mp3
  mv __out.mp3 $f
done
IFS=$SAVEIFS
```

This works fine if I go folder by folder and execute this command, but I'd like to have a "global" command, like in 4DOS, so I can run:

```
$ cd iTunes/Music
$ global normalize_mp3.sh
```

and the `global` command would traverse all subdirs and execute the `normalize_mp3.sh` to strip all my mp3 in all subfolders.

Does anyone know if there is a Unix equivalent to the 4DOS `global` command? I tried to play with `find -exec` but I just get a headache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very basic implementation of the described `global` command for `bash`:

```
global() {
  shopt -s globstar
  origdir="$PWD"
  for i in **/; do
    cd "$i"
    echo -n "${PWD}: "
    eval "$@"
    echo
    cd "$origdir"
  done
}
```

- `shopt -s globstar` [enables recursive globbing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49913/33390) with `**` (I think you'll need bash version >= 4)
- `**/` finds all directories below the current working dir, so `$i` loops over those
- I included a `echo` so you can see in which dir the loop currently is
- `eval "$@"` evaluates all arguments of the function
- `cd $origdir` goes back to the original directory. (At first I had an IMHO more elegant approach with `pushd` / `popd`, but I think cd back to `$origdir` is more bullet-proof in case the command `"$@"` itself changes the directory (which of course is a bad idea!)

This `global` command takes commands with arguments like `global touch foo`. If you want to use more advanced shell syntax like redirects or variables, you have to enclose the command in single-quotes `'...'`. But if your desire is to run your script `normalize_mp3.sh` in every directory the usage is as simple as

```
global normalize_mp3.sh
```

*Be aware, that the start of the first command can need some time to gather all subdirs if there are a lot of them.*

And, of course, please test with an up-to-date backup of your files!

---

Here is how it works (I can only test with Linux, but I assume that bash is working on OSX the same way):

```
$ echo $BASH_VERSION 
4.1.5(1)-release
$ cd /var
$ tree -d | head
.
├── backups
├── cache
│   ├── apt
│   │   ├── apt-file
│   │   └── archives
│   │       └── partial
│   ├── cups
│   │   └── rss
│   ├── debconf
$ global 'echo -n This command is executed in $PWD at $(date); sleep 1'
/var/backups: This command is executed in /var/backups at Mo 1. Jul 12:11:00 CEST 2013
/var/cache: This command is executed in /var/cache at Mo 1. Jul 12:11:01 CEST 2013
/var/cache/apt: This command is executed in /var/cache/apt at Mo 1. Jul 12:11:02 CEST 2013
/var/cache/apt/apt-file: This command is executed in /var/cache/apt/apt-file at Mo 1. Jul 12:11:03 CEST 2013
/var/cache/apt/archives: This command is executed in /var/cache/apt/archives at Mo 1. Jul 12:11:04 CEST 2013
/var/cache/apt/archives/partial: This command is executed in /var/cache/apt/archives/partial at Mo 1. Jul 12:11:05 CEST 2013
/var/cache/cups: This command is executed in /var/cache/cups at Mo 1. Jul 12:11:07 CEST 2013
/var/cache/cups/rss: This command is executed in /var/cache/cups/rss at Mo 1. Jul 12:11:08 CEST 2013
/var/cache/debconf: This command is executed in /var/cache/debconf at Mo 1. Jul 12:11:09 CEST 2013
...
```

Comment: in my understanding this is not really recursive, but thanks for trying, you've been the only one: you get +50

Comment: Still I feel the question is quite interesting...

Comment: What do you understand by "really recursive"? This command does "traverse all subdirs" and executes a command in every of those dirs. Is it not working with your setup? To get it working you must use a recent bash version (>= 4.0) -- I suppose bash is working on OSX the same way as on Linux?!

Comment: In the meantime I have an idea how to incorporate variables etc. in the command (I'll improve my answer later) -- it's so simple, but sometimes you simply have to stand back and get a glance of the whole.

Comment: That's fantastic. I wonder why something like this is missing in unix utils. You should improve this tool and open source this.

Comment: @LuigiR.Viggiano: Thanks -- I already open-sourced it, here on SU `:)` Btw. I think in the Unix world it's more common to use globbing.

Comment: "cd -" does the work of "cd $orig_dir": global() { for i in **/ ; do cd $i; eval "$@"; cd -; done }

Comment: @LuigiR.Viggiano: Yes, `cd -` is similar to `popd`. But I decided against its usage so that nothing breaks, if the command somehow manages to change the path. (`global cd ..` would be a minimal example). Regarding the wildcards I agree, `**/` is enough. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Other options:

```
find ~/Music -name \*.mp3 | while IFS= read -r f; do
  lame --cbr "$f" "$f"_temp
  mv "$f"_temp "$f"
done
```

```
mdfind 'kMDItemAudioBitRate>128000' -onlyin ~/Music |\
parallel lame --cbr {} {}_temp \; mv {}_temp {}
```

```
f() { lame --cbr "$1" "$1"_temp; mv "$1"_temp "$1"; }
export -f f
mdfind 'kMDItemAudioBitRate>128000' -onlyin ~/Music | parallel f
```

```
shopt -s globstar # bash 4.0 or later
for f in ~/Music/**/*.mp3; do lame --cbr "$f" "$f"_temp; mv "$f"_temp "$f"; done
```

Comment: +1 This definitely is a task for `find`. Even if you don't want to modify your script, you can limit the `find` command to only output directories and have your script run through them.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
# first cd to iTunes/Music
for f in */*/*.mp3
do 
  lame --cbr "$f" __out.mp3 && mv __out.mp3 "$f"
done
```

There is no need for setting `IFS`. You need to put double quotes around `$f` though..
I don't know if lame has a return code if something goes wrong. Perhaps first try it out with `printf "%s\n" "$f" first` instead of the lame command..

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have a slightly leaner script that [loops through the arguments provided to the script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79343/how-to-loop-through-arguments-in-a-bash-script).

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
for f do
  lame --cbr "$f" "$f_out.mp3"
  mv "$f_out.mp3" "$f"
done
```

To have it accessible from anywhere, put the script somewhere in your $PATH. On Linux, I'd use `$HOME/bin`, which is added to the $PATH by default; I suspect this is true of OSX too.

Use it on a single directory of mp3s with:

```
downrate_mp3 ./*.mp3
```

I prefer to prefix these globs with `./`, since it is legal to start filenames with a `-`, which can cause problems as many programs (including `mv`) expects arguments beginning with a `-` to be an option, rather than a file. For recursiveness, the best way is to use globstar (requires bash 4+, but I think that's what recent OSX has):

```
shopt -s globstar
downrate_mp3 ./**/*.mp3
```

Alternatively, you can use find with `-exec`, as you've already tried:

```
find iTunes/Music -type f -name '*.mp3' -exec downrate_mp3 {} +
```

The reason this wouldn't work with your existing command is that `find` is essentially trying to use the big list of files as arguments to the script -- and since the script in your question doesn't do anything with arguments, this obviously wouldn't work.